# Class inheritance in python with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm working on a hobby game, and i'm not able to get one class to inherit another properly. The file structure is as shown below:

```
main.py
Enemy
    |walker.py
    |genericEnemy.py
```

main.py calls walker.py, whose main class inherits from genericEnemy.py. Both of their contents are below:

walker.py

```
import pygame
from .genericEnemy import generic

class walker(generic):
    pass
```

genericEnemy.py

```
'''
    This class controls generic capabilities for all enemies.
    Specific abilities are in the enemy type's class in the superfolder
'''

import pygame

class generic:
    def __init__(self, speed, pos, size):
        '''
            speed - The entity speed, an int greater than 0
            pos - The (x,y) position of the entity, a list of length 2
            size - The entity hitbox, a list with length 2
        '''

        #Movement Variables
        self.speed = speed
        self.currDir = 1
        self.isMoving = True

        #Drawing Variables
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size

        #Gravity Variables
        self.isJumping = False
        self.fallCounter = 0
        self.gravityTimer = 0

#==================================================

        def draw(self, surface):
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.size[0], self.size[1]))

#==================================================

        def updateGravity(self):
            self.fallCounter += 1
            
            if self.fallCounter == 8:
                self.fallCounter = 0
                self.gravityTimer += 1

#==================================================

        def walk(self):
            if self.isMoving:
                self.pos[0] += self.speed * self.currDir
```

The issue I'm having is that in main when I say:

```
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
ENEMY = walker(6, [120, 1000], [10, 30])
```

and then later on

```
ENEMY.draw(SCREEN)
```

I get the error: AttributeError: 'walker' object has no attribute 'draw'

Any help would be greatly appreciated, like I said this is a hobbyist project, so i'm fairly inexperienced in python/pygame

Comment: The indentation in the `generic` class is wrong. You have all your other methods inside the `__init__` method. De-indent them one level.

Comment: This is not an inheritance problem. You would have the same problem if you created an instance of `generic` without inheriting.

Answer (score 1):

User Barmar was correct. I, as an absolute walnut, had my functions indented too far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `class generic(pygame.sprite.Sprite):` 
and

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(ENEMY)
all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)
```

pygame sprite group has 

[draw function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw)
 
And maybe it need sprite.image! 
It can be surface

```
self.image = pygame.Surface([self.size[0], self.size[1]])
self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
```

or image file

```
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(imgname).convert_alpha(), (self.size[0], self.size[1]))
```